# Adding events to Google Calendar from Windows desktop app/Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-calendar

I am looking for a desktop software or Google Chrome extension that would allow me to quickly add events to Google Calendar. A perfect application for me would have the ability to launch a dialog box through keyboard shortcut, fill event data and then post it to Google Calendar.

It could have many more functionalities, but the most important thing for me is to be able to quickly add an event (with an option to select a calendar I own/share with someone).

Comment: so you have chrome .. and .. you dont use the calendar from within chrome to add an event?

Comment: The problem is I don't want to have GCal tab open all the time.

Comment: why? extensions in chrome are a separate process as well. the space for a pinned tab is almost nil.

Comment: Still, it is a distraction and most of the times I use this tab just to add new event.

Comment: the pinned tab is a big as an extension button. i don't see the point.

Comment: It's a tab. I use keyboard shortcuts a lot and I a minimalist but you don't have to understand it.

Comment: Pinned tab will be your first one in the list. So do the key combo with Chrome open: `CTRL`+`1` -> `C` and create your event.